# jQuery Droppable: Only allow element to drop, if there is no other element in that dropzone

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm writing a puzzle, where you have to drag an item into the correct dropzone.

Problem: I want that you can only drag an item into a dropzone, if that dropzone does not contain any other items. How can I check, whether there are no other items in that dropzone?

Here is a gif of my current puzzle:
[image]

Here is a gif which shows the problem:

[image]

As you can see, I can drag multiple items into the same dropzone.

If a dropzone already contains an item, the user should not be able to drop another item into that dropzone. How do I achieve that?

My script so far:

```
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert: 'invalid', snap: ".dropfield", snapTolerance: 30, snapMode: "inner"});

        $( ".dropfield" ).droppable({
            accept: ".dropling",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {

              if(some-condition){ // if correct word got dragged into the correct dropzone
                  var id = ui.draggable.attr('id');
                  $("#" + id).draggable( 'disable' );
                  $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
                  $("#" + id).css( "background-color", "#7FFF00");
            }
        });
```

Html-excerpt:

```
<div id="liebe" class="dropling draggable text-center">
  Liebe
</div>

   <span class="dropfield" value="scheitern">

    </span>
```

PS: There are already several topics on Stack-Overflow with the same question. However, I'm not intelligent enough to apply the suggested answers to my case. Please help me.

Edit1

Here is a gif which shows my preferred behavior:

[image]

I dragged a wrong word into a dropzone. But as long that dropzone is occupied by a word, no other words should be able to be dropped into that dropzone.

My current code:

```
            if(some-condition){ //correct word


                $("#" + id).draggable( 'disable' );
                $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
                $("#" + id).css( "background-color", "#7FFF00");

                }
            } else { //wrong word
                console.log("wrong word dropped");
                $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
            }
```

As soon as I drag the wrong word out of the dropzone, the dropzone should become enabled again. But how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can disable `.droppable()` after the item is dropped.

Comment: @Twisty This can be done by doing this: $(this).droppable( 'disable' ); But how can I enable the droppable again? The docs mention the option of "out" (moving the draggable out of the dropzone), but it didn't work out very well. First, for some reason, the out-function does sometimes not trigger, second, if you move a draggable item over another dropzone, without dropping it, you enable that dropzone, even if it still has an item. But maybe I was doing it wrong. Can you maybe give me some instructions?

Comment: I posted an answer. I suspect it will not take you all the way to where you want to be. It will get you going and may help you reach your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise breaking this into their own functions. This way you can enable and disable drop repeatedly. Not sure what you want to trigger the item to become draggable and droppable again based on the example you have supplied. Based on what you have supplied, I can offer this the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function enableDrop($target) {
    console.log("Enabled Drop");
    $target.droppable({
      accept: ".dropling",
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "drop-target"
      },
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $that = $(this),
          dragWord = ui.draggable.text().trim(),
          $item = ui.draggable;
        if (checkWord(dragWord)) {
          console.log("Accepted: " + $item.attr("id"));
          $item.
          removeClass("draggable")
            .draggable('disable')
            .attr("style", "")
            .appendTo($that);
          disableDrop($that);
          $that.css("background-color", "#7FFF00");
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function disableDrop($target) {
    console.log("Disabling Drop on " + $target.attr("class"));
    $target.droppable("destroy");
  }

  function checkWord(w) {
    var result = false;
    console.log("Checked Word: " + w);
    if (w == "Liebe") {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'valid',
    snap: ".dropfield",
    snapTolerance: 30,
    snapMode: "inner"
  });

  enableDrop($(".dropfield"));
});
```

```css
p .dropfield {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: -.25em
}

p .drop-target {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.draggable {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 1em;
  padding: .25em 0;
  margin-bottom: -.25em
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Diese Schlussfolgerung ist <span class="dropfield" value="scheitern"></span>: Ee kann doch nicht sein, dass es gut ist, </p>

<div id="liebe" class="dropling draggable text-center">Liebe</div>
<div id="absurd" class="dropling draggable text-center">absurd</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way here is probably to solve the whole thing in a more generic way. For this I would add an attribute to the respective Dom element (data-count) and then check how many characters are contained and how many are still allowed:

See `/** ADDED **/` for the things i did:

```js
$(function() {
  function textWrapper(str, sp, btn) {
    if (sp == undefined) {
      sp = [0, 0];
    }
    var txt = "";
    if (btn) {
      txt = "<span class='w b'>" + str + "</span>";
    } else {
      txt = "<span class='w'>" + str + "</span>";
    }

    if (sp[0]) {
      txt = "&nbsp;" + txt;
    }

    if (sp[1]) {
      txt = txt + "&nbsp;";
    }

    return txt;
  }

  function chunkWords(p) {
    var words = p.split(" ");
    words[0] = textWrapper(words[0], [0, 1]);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
      var re = /\[.+\]/;
      if (re.test(words[i])) {
        var b = makeTextBox(words[i].slice(1, -1));
        words[i] = "&nbsp;" + b.prop("outerHTML") + "&nbsp;";
      } else {
        if (words[0].indexOf(".")) {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 0]);
        } else {
          words[i] = textWrapper(words[i], [1, 1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return words.join("");
  }

  function unChunkWords(tObj) {
    var words = "";
    $(tObj).contents().each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).hasClass("b")) {
        words += "[" + $(el).text() + "]";
      } else {
        words += $(el).text();
      }
    });
    return words.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  }

  function makeBtn(tObj) {
    var btn = $("<span>", {
      class: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
    }).appendTo(tObj);
  }

  function makeTextBox(txt) {
    var sp = $("<span>", {
      class: "w b"
    }).html(txt);
    makeBtn(sp);
    return sp;
  }

  function makeDropText(obj) {
    return obj.droppable({
      drop: function(e, ui) {
        var txt = ui.draggable.text();
        var newSpan = textWrapper(txt, [1, 0], 1);
        $(this).after(newSpan);
        makeBtn($(this).next("span.w"));
        makeDropText($(this).next("span.w"));
        $("span.w.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        
        update()
      },
      over: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      },
      out: function() {
        $(this).add($(this).next("span.w")).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
      }
    });
  }

  $("p.given").html(chunkWords($("p.given").text()));

  $("p.given").on("click", ".b > .ui-icon", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

  $("p.given").blur(function() {
    var w = unChunkWords($(this));
    $(this).html(chunkWords(w));
    makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));
  });

  $("span.given").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  makeDropText($("p.given span.w"));

  /** ADDED **/
  // update at beginning
  update();
  // register update events
  $("p.given").on('click keydown keyup drag drop', update);
  
  
  function update(e) {
    var templateText = unChunkWords($("p.given"));
    var templateTextWithoutParameters = templateText.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "");
    var templateTextWithoutParametersLenght = templateTextWithoutParameters.length;

    // calc total length
    var totalLength = templateTextWithoutParametersLenght;
    // since 'helper: clone' we have to ignore it!
    $("[data-count]:not(.ui-draggable-dragging)").each(function(index, item) {
      var count = $(item).attr("data-count")
      var text = "[" + $(item).text() + "]";
      var length = templateText.split(text).length - 1;
      totalLength += count * length;
    }); 

    // 46,8 keycodes for delete & backspace
    var maxLength = 200;
    if (totalLength >= maxLength && e && e.keyCode !== 46 && e.keyCode !== 8) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    // disable data counts
    var remaining = maxLength - totalLength;
    $("[data-count]:not(.ui-draggable-dragging)").each(function(index, item) {
      var count = $(item).attr("data-count");
      if (parseInt(count) > remaining) {
        $(item).attr("disabled", true);
        $(item).draggable().draggable('disable');
      } else {
        $(item).attr("disabled", false);
        $(item).draggable().draggable('enable');
      }
    })

    $(".output").text(totalLength);
  }
});
```

```css
p.given {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p.given span.w span.ui-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.blanks {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

div.blanks.ui-droppable-active {
  min-height: 20px;
}

span.answers>b {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

span.given {
  margin: 5px;
}

/** ADDED **/
[disabled] {
  color: grey
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p class="given" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum is [Test] Ipsum has been the industry's [America] standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>
</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="section">
  <section>
    <div class="card blue-grey ">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="1" data-count="50">Test</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="2" data-count="30">America</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="3" data-count="20">Qatar</span>
            <span class="given btn-flat white-text red lighten-1" rel="4" data-count="10">Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>


<div class="divider"></div>
Count: <span class="output"></span>
```